# Is there another name for compound "delta-7 sterine", does it exist alone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, identification, steroids

Is there a more common name for "delta-7 sterine"? Is this spelled correct?

I read all over the internet and this compound exists in many articles, but I cannot find any information on it at all, also it doesn't show any information it. Can you please direct me to more information on this compound on what it is, it's more common names, chemical makeup, etc. All I could find in articles is that it's a steroid found in pumpkin seeds.

I would like to buy this compound for experimenting but cannot find a supplier that recognizes this name of the compound, does it exist alone in this form?

Comment: E-commerce and related questions about buying/selling are considered off-topic on Chemistry.SE (I edited your question accordingly to meet the requirements).

Answer (score 6):

"delta-7 sterine" seems to be an adaptation of German term "Sterine" (plural for "Sterin") used by German scientists who elucidated the structures of those steroids using NMR [[1](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-1968-0109)].
In English, it seems, the name should be written as **Δ⁷–sterol** and is not a single compound but a group of compounds (for more info I'd suggest searching Google Scholar).

#### References

1. Sucrow, W.; Reimerdes, A. Δ⁷-Sterine Aus Cucurbitaceen. *Zeitschrift für Naturforschung B* **1967**, 23 (1), 42–45. https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-1968-0109. (Open Access)